# Django is automatically adding an ID field during unit tests even though I declared a primary key for my model

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django project with multiple tables and am in charge of writing unit tests for the api of said django project. One of the tables has a ForeignKey of a different table, however when I try to create the model object in a unit test I get the following IntegrityError after the model object the ForeignKey refers to is successfully queried, despite being able to post data to this table while the server is running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_examplemodel.location_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~\tests\test_example_model.py", line 19, in test_post_example_model_valid       
    response = self.client.post(reverse("examplemodelurl"), EXAMPLE_MODEL_DICT, content_type="application/json")

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_examplemodel.location_id
```

Here is the unit test **(it throws the error before I get the chance to assert anything)**:

```
class TestPostExampleModel(TestCase):
    def test_post_example_model_valid(self):
        self.client.post(reverse("locations"), {"name": "location name"}, content_type="application/json")
        response = self.client.post(reverse("examplemodelurl"), {"name": "example name", "location": "location name"}, content_type="application/json")
```

The main confusing thing about this is that on the official django site, it says the following about model autofields:

[**If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Here are the relevant model definitions

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, unique=True)
    location_type = models.CharField(default='other', max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name}'

class BaseExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, primary_key=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

ExampleModel(BaseExampleModel):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And here are the serializers I am using to validate those models:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import *

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = "__all__"

class ExampleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

If what the django docs say is correct, an ID field shouldn't be created for the location model, however the NOT NULL constraint fails on app_examplemodel.location_id after the query to get the location object is completed. The error goes away if I put `null=True` in the foreign key definition, but instead of allowing the value to be null, it just winds up always being null. I have other models with ForeignKeys in this project and they behave as expected.

My guess is that it has something to do with examplemodel being a child of an abstract model, but that doesn't explain why I can post data to this model successfully when the server is running, but not during unittests. My sanity is slowly draining, I have been unable to find any forum posts or docs that explain why this is happening, and I would really like to be doing anything else with my time right now.

please send help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following code:

```
ExampleModel(BaseExampleModel):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

It requires you to specify an actual `ForeignKey` to a `Location` object when you are calling the post.

The `location_id` is a field created in your Django model object by Django. This holds the reference to the actual `id` of the `Location` object you have assigned.

The correct way to create a `ExampleModel` object is the following:

```
location = Location.objects.create(name='foo', adress='foo')
example_model = ExampleModel.objects.create(name='bar', location=location)
```

In your test that would look something like

```
class TestPostExampleModel(TestCase):
    def test_post_example_model_valid(self):

        # You need to have a location object to create an examplemodel
        location = Location.objects.create(name='foo', adress='foo')
  
        # Here you see "location": location.id
        response = self.client.post(reverse("examplemodelurl"), {"name": "example name", "location": location.id}, content_type="application/json")
```

It works when you set `null=True` because `null=True` allows the `location` to be null. You could still edit the location by assigning a location object to it and call `.save()` on the `ExampleModel` object.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked, thanks! You can even still use a serializer for validation as long as you create the object like you specified above and then plug that model object into the serializer